# Как правильно реализовать систему очередей для асинхронного подтверждения авторизации, путем ожидания кода

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, puppeteer

Имеется `puppeteer` сервер который выполняет авторизацию на сервере, он служит в качестве удобной авторизации над сервисом, предлагая возможность в качестве мультиаккаунтности. Проще говоря, свой сервис, который дополняет другой сервис, который этого сделать не может.

Существует разовая авторизация с подтверждением по СМС коду, код вводится вручную, затем аккаунт добавляется в базу и в дальнейшем допускается возможность заходить из под разных устройств в одном месте.

В чем заключается проблема:

При заполнении первичных данных, для входа требуется подтверждение, по смс, первичный вход заключается в подстановке данных пользователя на сервис, это выполняется асинхронно и необходимо дождаться смс подтверждения для входа.

Данную систему я организовал через брокер сообщений RabbitMQ.
В брокер поступают сообщения, а дальше эти сообщения идут на сервер, там они выполняются.

Система авторизации в брокере разбита на две части.

1. Получение первичных данных (логин / пароль).
2. Подтверждение входа через СМС код.

Я сделал две очереди которые независимо друг от друга получают данные и код, поэтому они разбиты.

Как организовать систему так, чтобы после ввода данных и обработки их, сервер ждал код?

Для себя я вижу два варианта решения задачи:

1. Внутри слушателя данных сделать еще один слушатель, который будет ждать код и проверять на соответствие, относится ли он к текущим данным (т.к. кодов может быть много и они будут доставляться к разным пользователям в разное время).
2. Создать слушатель на одном уровне с авторизацией и завести переменную, в которую буду помещать все пришедшие коды и удалять их из переменной по истечению времени. Данную переменную я буду смотреть через Proxy и если находить соответствия выполнять свои действия дальше.

Какой из этих вариантов более правильный?

Какой вообще есть вариант выхода из данной ситуации?

Я просто хотел ждать код для своей очереди чтобы применить действие, но сделать это непосредственно в ней или же один раз за ее пределами, вот в чем заключается вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать очереди сообщений в режиме `Запрос-Ответ`, такого режима следует избегать. Использование этого шаблона зачастую и приводит к решению проблем, которых не должно возникать *(создание потребителя внутри потребителя)* или излишнему усложнению системы, когда приходится создавать `Саги`, чтобы корректно отработать многоступенчатый процесс.
Вместо `запрос-ответ` гораздо лучше использовать `событийную архитектуру`, когда вместо категорий запросов вы начинаете мыслить категориями событий.
В случае описанного вами процесса, событийную архитектуру можно описать следующим образом:

1. Пользователь ввёл логин-пароль в сервисе **`А`** - в очередь отправляется событие `ICredentialsReceived`.
2. Сервис-подписчик **`Б`** получает событие и выполняет потребление - проверяет логин-пароль, сохраняет и отправляет временный СМС-код и публикует событие `ISmsCodeSent`.
3. Сервис-подписчик **`А`** получает событие и переключает пользователя на страницу ввода СМС-кода.
4. После ввода СМС-кода, сервис **`А`** отправляет событие `ISmsCodeSubmit` с введённым кодом.
5. Сервис-подписчик **`Б`** получает событие, сверяет СМС-код с сохранённым и если всё правильно, то отправляет событие `ILoginSucceeded`.
6. Сервис-подписчик **`А`** получает событие и пропускает пользователя в систему.

В событийной парадигме вам не приходится сталкиваться с описанными вами сложностями. Но у всего есть своя цена - в таком режиме обычно происходит небольшое усложнение процесса коммуникации *(больше фаз, событий, обработчиков)*.

Comment: Вы отлично раскрыли ответ на мой вопрос!