# Реализация системы личных сообщений на сайте с помощью node.js и websocket

Tags: websocket

Всем привет! Я хочу делать систему личных сообщений на сайте, желательно PHP+MYSQL. Остановился на обновлении чата для получения новых сообщений без перезагрузки страницы и без отправки запроса через каждое определенное количество секунд. Решил использовать websocket. Понял, что его нужно будет установить на VDS, а на обычном хостинге он никак не будет работать, и что его нужно будет написать только на nodeJs. А по nodeJs я вообще ничего не знаю. По разным материалам в интернете я по всякому пытался реализовать, но никак не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста стратегию действий, можете дать ссылки на только такие материалы, где все очень подробно написано, чтобы было понятно новичку. Или был бы очень признателен, если вы сами могли подробно объяснить тут. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Лучше уж использовать [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/) для обмена сообщений в режиме реального времени. На клиенте слушаете ивент `message`, на сервере при поступлении сообщения делаете `emit` на подключенного клиента. Каждому клиенту после авторизации можно дать `id` из базы, чтобы удобнее находить и отсылать сообщения, а как вы будете ловить сообщения на сервере уже другой вопрос, я бы использовал [очереди](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) и [архитектуру событий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205680)