# Как получить результат работы потребителя при работе с очередями (через RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, сервисы, микросервисы

Не совсем понимаю как получить результат работы потребителя при работе с очередями.

Сразу начну с примера. Допустим у нас клиента сайта, использует сервис 1. Этот сервис 1 для своей работы должен зарегистрировать пользователя, а значит он отправляет запрос в сервис 2 (который отвечает за регистрацию), в ответ на свой запрос получает ID пользователя.
В случае очередей.
Сервис 1, наполняет очередь своим запросом. Сервис 2, получает сообщение и обрабатывает его. Как теперь Сервис 2, вернёт результат Сервису 1, или как Сервис 1, может сам получить результат обработки своего сообщения Сервисом 2.

Comment: Самое простое и очевидное - если общение должно быть двухсторонним, то завести второй канал с очередью сообщений от 2 сервиса к 1.

Comment: Я тоже об этом подумал с самого начала, но тогда разве не будет проблем, если 100 пользователей одновременно будут пользоваться Сервисом 1. Выходит, что Сервис 1, как-то должен понимать, какому пользователю, какой результат из очереди возвращать. А так же если пользователь ушёл, то выходить его очередь должна очиститься.

Или же вы имеете ввиду отдельный канал для каждого пользователя? И если пользователь ушёл, то очередь очищается. Если ждёт результат, то получит только свой результат, по своему уникальному каналу?

Comment: Задача очереди, получить сообщение от получателя и отдать одному из потребителей и забыть. Если потребитель хочет обратный канал до получателя, то это в задачи очередей не входит. Вообще очереди обычно используют для долгих процессов и результат обработки можно куда-то сохранить или кому-то еще передать дальше.

Comment: Сервис 1 по-любому должен уметь идентифицировать пользователей (обычно по токенам или куки). Если 100 пользователей пользуются сервисом 1, ничего страшного в этом самом по себе нет. Если пользователь ушел, то от него данных больше нет, а данные ему - протухают и пропадают (TTL). Также, учтите, что то как сервис 1 общается с сервисом 2 никак не связано с тем, как пользователи общаются с сервисом 1. Сервис 1 и 2 могут общаться по паре каналов при любом числе пользователей. Если же вам понадобится масштабирование, то это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Типовым решением является создание Сервисом 1 уникальной собственной очереди (обычно с флагом exclusive) и передача ее имени вместе с запросом. Сервис 2 шлет в нее ответ.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое. Жаль, что ваши ответы в комментах) Можно было бы проголосовать.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь работать с очередями в режиме "запрос-ответ", а это нежелательно как раз из-за возникновения подобных вопросов. Вместо этого ваш код должен реагировать на события из брокера, а приложение писаться в событийной парадигме (если задача к этому располагает). Посмотрите мой подробный ответ на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205680